Sysbench Fails with mysql_stmt_execute Error Despite Successful Manual Query Execution via Mycat()
I am attempting to run a read-only Sysbench benchmark against a Mycat instance (acting as a distributed database middleware), using the command:
sysbench ./oltp_read_only.lua --mysql-db=zzz-test --mysql-user=xxx --mysql-password=xxx --mysql-host=xxx --mysql-port=8066 --tables=10 --threads=1 --report-interval=10 --time=60 run

when I debug with Mycat, it goes well and got the Result Set successfully. But sysbench went wrong, print error info:

Threads started!
FATAL: mysql_stmt_execute() returned error 0 () for query 'SELECT c FROM sbtest3 WHERE id BETWEEN ? AND ?'
FATAL: `thread_run' function failed: ./oltp_common.lua:432: SQL error, errno = 0, state = '00000': **

Curiously, the reported SQL error state ('00000') usually denotes a successful operation in MySQL context, adding to the confusion.
so I replace MyCat with a real MySql server, and everthing went well and I got the sysbench stats;
what's wrong ?
Environment Details:
Sysbench Version: [1.0.20]
Mycat Version: [1.6.7.6]
I am seeking assistance to identify the root cause of this anomaly and steps to ensure the Sysbench benchmark operates seamlessly in line with the manual execution outcomes. Any insights, troubleshooting tips, or configuration adjustments that could resolve this issue are welcome.
thanks
